# App Crashes on Returning from browser

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Main Activity which Opens a Fragment like this.

```
Fragment fragment = null;

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new MyFragment();
    break;
default:
    break;
}

if (fragment != null) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();

}
```

This Fragment contains a List View. On Taping the list item New Activity Opened like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

From this Activity I opened a link in browser like this.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Now here is the issue. If we opens a simple web link it works fine but if link contains an Application link of Play Store, on returning back from browser App crashed. On Htc and Nexus devices it is working fine but on Samsung S3 App crashed on returning from browser.

From Debuging i found that my Main fragment is null on Samsung S3 devices.

My Log Cat shows this.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codenterprise.CashbackKorting/com.codenterprise.left.fragment.shops.ShopComplateDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codenterprise.general.Services.<init>(Services.java:74)
    at com.codenterprise.general.Services.<init>(Services.java:70)
    at com.codenterprise.left.fragment.shops.ShopComplateDetailActivity.onCreate(ShopComplateDetailActivity.java:90)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
```

Thanks

Comment: post your logcat here,while returning from browser

Comment: show your line at Services.java:  74 line

Comment: DatabaseService.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()); this my Line 74. Actually Context of MainActivity is Null Here.

Comment: i think the class context get the nullpointer exception,

Comment: Yes you are right, but why the context is null on samsung S3.

Comment: Uri.parse(url)--in this URL is String,can you post url code

Comment: pls check the same in other samsung devices except s3,and then let me know whats happening

Comment: How you obtained the 'context' reference that you passed to the ctor of Services class? Is Services class a Fragment or just a pojo? What browser do you use on the S3? Is this one made by Samsung? Have you tried with Google Chrome on the S3?

Comment: @Boopathi Its showing same behavior on devices having Ram equal or less then 1GB. For devices Having Ram Greater then 1GB, It is working fine.

Comment: @dumpstate Service class is just a pojo and It showing same result for Google Chrome on S3.

Comment: @user3789702 Now you want to check Heap size stats in less than one GB and Grater than 1 GB devices.At that time you have to check How GC is handled.Keep in your mind every devices JVM is unique not same

Comment: @Boopathi Can you please tell me how to check heap size..?

Comment: But how you obtain the context reference for the Service class?

Comment: @Boopathi debug.heap native: allocated 22.81MB of 23.33MB (0.52MB free) debug.memory: allocated: 19.00MB of 96.00MB (2.00MB free) these are for 1GB Ram

Comment: its allocation is happening in between my activity and browser task.Am i right

Comment: @Boopathi yes, you are right

Comment: I think DatabaseService is destroyed when u come back. What is this service?

Comment: can you post MyActivity.java code

Comment: Thanks everybody, Its solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Devices with less memory kills your application to save memory when your application goes to background. So try to save and restore the state of your application before and after going to browser, like in the below code

Save the state

```
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }
```

and retrieve it in the same activity

```
@Override
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 }
```

Comment: I have a similar problem in one mobile has a low memory . when I click back from browser it shows a blanc white screen then it restarts the app . there are no logs and I don't know why it make this behavior

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the app being killed?